# scanf_s skips in Visual Studio

Tags: c

```
do {
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    if (a < 1 || a > 10) {
        printf("Incorrect input\n");
    }
} while (a < 1 || a > 10);
```

When entering a character instead of an integer number, the compiler skips sсanf and goes into an infinite loop. help me figure out why this happens.

[when debugging, the value of the variable contains this data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2q3ZK.png)

Comment: If the input cannot be converted to an integer `scanf` returns an error and leaves the input in the buffer, forever. That's why you always check the return value so you know if it succeeded or failed.

Comment: [The program only runs after the compiler has finished, so it isn't accurate to say that the compiler skips scanf.]

Comment: The `scanf` expects formatted input, not user mistakes. Although it's possible to clear the garbage stuck in the input buffer, it is easier to used `fgets` and apply `sscanf` instead. Then when the scan function reports no conversion (which you didn't check), you can forget the string input and get another.

Comment: You use `a` without assigning a value first. If `scanf_s` fails it will still contain indetermined value and using it causes undefined behaviour. You ignore the return value, which is always a bad idea. You must use return type of `scanf_s` to verify if the input was converted successfully and only then use the input value for any further operation.